# ADF prod object pipeline parametrization not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created an object param in the dev environment in my ADF instance like {"SuperSet":"SuperSet/SuperSet.csv"}, and calling the object like `pipeline().parameters.DWH.SuperSet` it is working fine, but when deployed on production instance using Azure CI/CD, it gives below mentioned error when triggered on set time.

`Operation on target SuperSet failed: The expression 'pipeline().parameters.DWH.SuperSet' cannot be evaluated because property 'SuperSet' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.`

my arm-templete-parameters-definition.json file has:

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
      "activities": [
        {
          "policy": {
            "retry": "-",
            "retryIntervalInSeconds": "-"
          }
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "defaultValue": "-::string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 0):

Had to update arm-templete-parameters-definition.json, and it worked.

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
      "activities": [
        {
          "policy": {
            "retry": "-",
            "retryIntervalInSeconds": "-"
          }
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "defaultValue": "-::string"
        },
        "DWH": {
          "type": "object",
          "defaultValue": "=::object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

After the adf_publish branch update you will find before and after mentioned below.

Before:

```
"Aport_Import_properties_parameters_DWH": {
            "type": "string"
        }
```

After:

```
"Aport_Import_properties_parameters_DWH": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "FILENAME": "techbit.csv"
            }
        }
```

**"FILENAME": "techbit.csv"** is the object that i had declared in the parameters in pipeline.